# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) what should i do to make it works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

```
asp.net code 
      List<s_data> sound = new List<s_data>();
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
         JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sd_users>(vals);
```

the class in the code above made by http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class sd_users
{
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string kind { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

json i need to deserialize

[{"kind":"track","id":134499880,"user":{"id":67127963,"kind":"user"]

Comment: That's a *huge* amount of JSON and a very large class. Please try to cut it down to a *short* example that still demonstrates the problem... and ideally make it a *complete* example, e.g. as a console app. (That's a lot easier to reproduce and diagnose than an ASP.NET app.)

Comment: i cut it down as possible as i can to make it obvious to what i want to do

Comment: Are you suggesting that *every single one* of those properties is required to reproduce the problem? I don't believe that.

Comment: i need only one of them

Comment: Right. The code's looking a lot simpler now - so the JSON can be reduced too... and then you could provide a short but complete console app, rather than a snippet of an ASP.NET app.

Comment: the JSON is a block and repeated and i delete all repeated blocks and i let only one block to make it obvious

Comment: But it's got *so* many more properties than you need. It's really important to be able to come up with minimal examples to demonstrate problems - both to help other people help you on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere), but also to help you help *yourself* when diagnosing issues.

Comment: i delete almost all of them except two of properties they what i need and for JSON the problem is its alot and nested but i will try to reduce them to make it easier

Answer (score 1):

you json is an array of objects. Use

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sd_users.RootObject>>(vals);
```

Comment: it works as you said but how can i get RootObject.id ?

Comment: @SherifMostafa Put a breakpoint, and see what you get after deserialization.

Comment: @SherifMostafa `I get nothing` doesn't mean anything. Can you explain what you did to get the id? Given your json and classes, it works.

Comment: i make a beakpoint in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sd_users>>(vals); to see what happens it opens a new tap calles no source avaliable

Comment: @SherifMostafa and what? Come on. what do you see when you type `arr[0].id`

Comment: @SherifMostafa Forget this answer for now and turn back to this post when you learnt something about json deserialization.

Comment: i knew that i can deserialize JSON and put it in an object which i can use its data easily does it wrong @EZI

Comment: when i make    `TextBox.Text = arr[0].ToString();` it returns `sd_users` just only